# Spring boot application not accessible on remote device(same network) after upgrade to Open JDK17

Tags: java, spring-boot, accessible

I have upgraded my spring boot application from JDK8 to open JDK 17.8+1.
Actually I am running two java versions(8 and 17) in my windows environment.
Before installing JDK17 when I connect my mobile application with Spring boot application(backend) with IPV4 and port everything was working fine.
Now(after 17), When I am trying to connect my mobile application to spring boot(backend) its failed to connect even the spring whitelable page is not accessible from device browser as well.

Need your help to kindly get is resolved.
Note I am using jar file.
Also please note I have tried -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true but no luck.

Thanks,
Mohsin

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is to check the firewall, maybe you allowed Java 8 to expose ports but not Java 17.

Comment: Thanks for response but there's no firewall restriction.